# Interpretation of autocorrelation function

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, correlation, stationary-processes, noise

In my study material I came across this:

*Interpretation of the autocorrelation function of a WSS process:*

*The autocorrelation function RX ( τ ) measures the correlation between two random
variables X ( t ) and X ( t + τ ). If RX ( τ ) drops quickly with respect to τ , then the
X ( t ) and X ( t + τ ) will be less correlated for large τ . This in turn means that the
signal has lot of changes with respect to time. Such a signal has high frequency
components. If RX ( τ ) drops slowly, the signal samples are highly correlated and
such a signal has less high frequency components.*

According to me this is possible only if the mean of Random Process is considered to be 0, because if the covariance is 0 and the mean is 5 then RX ( τ ) would be 25 which would give a false impression that the process is highly correlated as it does not quickly drop but its uncorrelated. Am I right with this justification?

Comment: No, I do not think your justification is correct. Autocorrelation RX ( τ ) is usually calculated by taking into consideration a set of observations   X ( t ) and X ( t + τ ) for various values of t, not just one particular t.

Comment: Say for 100 timestamps the covariance function is 0 and then decreases to -1 from 101 to 120th timestamp. The signal is surely not highly correlated as the for the major time the covariance is 0. But if the mean is 5 then the autocorrelation function becomes 25 for the 1st 100 timestamps and then decreases to 24 from 101 to 120th timestamp. Since the autocorrelation drops slowly, according to the my study material, the function is highly correlated. Isn't this contradicting?

Comment: Why do you say that when mean is 5, the autocorrelation becomes 25?

Comment: Cov = Rx - mean^2 for WSS. So if Rx = Cov + mean^2. This means if mean is 5 then Rx is 5^2=25

Comment: I'm sorry. Never heard such definition of autocorrelation. Better check the text author once.